# VB.Net - Play file extension that does not match the file format?

Tags: vb.net, windows, media-player, file-extension

I'm creating an app in VB.NET windows form Application..
On my App I have Media Player Library and I am playing .mp3 files, now I change the extension of my files into .albs to be little realistic with my app name..
But after i change the extension and when I try to play files I get this:

[image]

When i click Yes app continues to work perfectly and to play my files...

When I click **"Don't ask me again for this extension (.albs)."** app works well..

***What I need ?***

I need to hide this windows, so when I install my app to other PCs I don't want this window to be opened..
So is anyway to stop this before it opens..
for example any .reg file to register the extension..
or some code to register in app or something else.. ??

Any help will be appreciated...

Comment: It means what is says - WMP looks at the file, sees it is really a known MIME type (audio/mpeg3) and tells the user such

Comment: I would assume that you would need to register that file type as being one that is executed by WMP, or at least add the exception that checking that "Don't ask me again" box does.  The former is easy enough but I'm not sure how the latter would be accomplished because I'm not sure where that information is stored.  Probably the Registry but exactly where might take some investigation.